# IndexError: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to code a decision matrix in python, so far I've got, setting up the 2 dimensional matrix, setting up lists to hold the titles of decision options and criteria, getting the amounts (of options and criteria) and titles from the user, and then getting the values of the criteria and the options, from the user.

I want to move on to the next step, making a decision based on those values, but I'm getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/std/dev/python/DM/DM0.0.2.py", line 56, in <module>
    print "\nOut of 10, how do you rate option %s for criteria %s?" % (optionNames[optionCount], criteriaNames[criteriaCount])
IndexError: list index out of range`

I have tried all sorts to fix it, rearranged the code using a few styles of flow control etc, I cant figure it out. As you can see from the full code, below, I have included a few print statements to give myself some feedback on exactly what's going on with the code, it seems right to me.. Can someone show me where I'm going wrong please? Thanks.

```
# DM2 - Decision Matrix 2

print "Decision Matrix"
print "Please enter integers"
bl = "------------------------------"
print bl
# Get the ammount of options and criteria to work with
print "How many options do you have?"
num_options = int(raw_input("> "))
print bl

print "How many criteria do you have?"
num_criteria = int(raw_input("> "))
print bl

# Define some lists to keep names of options and criteria
optionNames = [0 for x in range(0, num_options)] 
criteriaNames = [0 for x in range(0, num_criteria)] 

# Define our matrix
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(0, num_criteria)] for x in range(0, num_options)] 

# Get names for options and criteria
count = 0
while count < num_options:
    modCount = count +1
    optionNames[count] = raw_input("Name option %s:" % modCount)
    count = count +1

print optionNames
print bl

count = 0
while count < num_criteria:
    modCount = count +1
    criteriaNames[count] = raw_input("Name criteria %s:" % modCount)
    count = count +1

print criteriaNames
print bl

# Print the matrix so far (should be empty)
print "The Matrix:"
print Matrix
print bl

print "\nNow we will talk about how well the options match the criteria."

#take scores out of 10 for the matrix
optionCount = 0
criteriaCount = 0

while criteriaCount < num_criteria * num_options +1:
    while optionCount < num_options:
        print "\nOut of 10, how do you rate option %s for criteria %s?" % (optionNames[optionCount], criteriaNames[criteriaCount])
        print Matrix
        print "opCount: ", optionCount
        print "critCount: ", criteriaCount
        criteriaScore = int(raw_input("> "))
        Matrix[optionCount][criteriaCount] = criteriaScore
        optionCount +=1
    criteriaCount +=1
    optionCount = 0
    while criteriaNames < num_criteria * num_options +1:
        while criteriaCount < num_criteria:
            print "\nOut of 10, how do you rate option %s for criteria %s?" % (optionNames[optionCount], criteriaNames[criteriaCount])
            print Matrix
            print "opCount: ", optionCount
            print "critCount: ", criteriaCount
            criteriaScore = int(raw_input("> "))
            Matrix[optionCount][criteriaCount] = criteriaScore
            optionCount +=1



# Calculate best decision based on the best scoring option
```

Comment: Sorted.

Using a double for loop was the solution, thanks a lot indmg.

Obviusly too many while loops was my problem, but I also tried adding the suggested prints and criteriaCount did not go higher than len(criteriaNames).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to enter a score for each criteria and option combination.

The problem is with your three whiles which screw up the indexing. A cleaner approach will be a double for loop:

```
for option in xrange(num_options):
    for criteria in xrange(num_criteria):
        # read input
        Matrix[option][criteria] = score
```

For cleaner list initialization you can use

```
[0]*num_options
```

If my understanding is correct and it matches your expectations, now try to rewrite this code into while loops to understand the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you print `optionCount`, `criteriaCount`, `len(optionNames)`, `len(criteriaNames)`, before the print statement that barks, you'll see that you are most likely mishandling your indexing, or that your `*Names` lists aren't populated as you'd expect.

Looking at the code, I'd bet that `criteriaCount` goes higher than `len(criteriaNames)`. Just a bit of a gamble though :)